# Import Wavefront .obj model to ARCore OpenGL project

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying out the java_arcore_hello_ar sample app but replacing the andy.obj with my own model created in Blender. I have exported the blender object using settings from [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-opengl-es-in-android-apps--cms-28464)

The .obj and .mtl files were placed in the assets folder but when I tap on the screen I get nothing. It doesn't show an error so I'm thinking it does place the object on the screen but is not drawing it for whatever reason.

Any Google searching for results generally bring up tutorials where you have to create a parser for converting the object, but as far as I can see, the ObjectRenderer class in arcore package does this heavy lifting for you.

Has anyone tried this with any success? Do I have to do further work with the .mtl file?

Comment: if you put the .obj in the proper directory and change the name of the resource in the code everything should go without any problem. Just remember that sample you`ve mentioned is working with texture. If your model does not contain it this may cause problems

Comment: I am also facing same issue, my obj file is also created in Wavefront and it has texture, then too nothing is getting displayed on tap, i am using multiple 3D models, all other model which wear downloaded from Google Poly was working, except Wavefront OBJ file, If any one knows the solution then please share

Answer (score 1):

I did get this worked by extending the code to reade OBJ and MTL files.

You can take a look at my code @ https://github.com/JohnLXiang/arcore-sandbox .

I'm also new to openGL, my code is not perfect but works at least.

Comment: It looks like the fragment shader that comes with the Google's sample requires the ambient, diffuse and specular values to be a single float, while these values defined in MTL are in r/g/b format....I haven't figured out how to resolve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

If it does't any error information , I think the reasons are:

1.The Obj model has been placed other position , for example far far place  . So you should check if model's position is origin of Blender in modeling process .
2.The Obj model is different one of java_arcore_hello_ar sample , so  when java_arcore_hello_ar sample's Obj parse library parsed error.

So, you can parse obj model by yourself.